# Non-Repeatable numbers into database - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, random, generator

Say I have a database created for testing purposes, Is there a way I can seed in data into a column, where the number a different so for example in my seed task :

```
10.times do
Post.create!(
  Start_Date: '' 
  End_Date: ''
  Number: "Random number from 1 to 10"
  )
end
```

It doesn't matter if the number is random or an increment from 1-10, as long as it's non-repeatable. Is there a gem out there that can do this maybe ?

Comment: Just use an incrementing index field, like an ID field. What you're asking for is a standard part of databases these days so you don't have to write anything, just define that column type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are fine with just a sequence 1..10 you can use this code

```
10.times do |i|
  Post.create!(
    Start_Date: '' 
    End_Date: ''
    Number: i + 1
  )
end
```

If you need random numbers:

```
(1..10).to_a.shuffle.each do |i|
  Post.create!(
    Start_Date: '' 
    End_Date: ''
    Number: i
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Gives you random number in the range of 1-10

```
  10.times do
    Post.create!(
      Start_Date: '' 
      End_Date: ''
      Number: rand(1..10)
      )
  end
```

Do the bulk creation so it just issues one query to create them all.

```
posts = []
10.times do
  posts << {Start_date: '', End_Date: '', Number: rand(1..10)}
end

Post.create(posts)
```